# Store http requests and execute them when the user is online, in ionic framework v1

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework

I want to save all the http requests (that user triggered while using the app) into some persistent storage (preferably sqlite) and execute them once the user is online. Is there a robust solution/library/angularjs-module to implement this?

Comment: service workers would be the best option for you.

Comment: @raj can you please elaborate or give examples to support your answer?